# thumbnail not loading in android

Tags: android, thumbnails

I am trying to load thumbnails and I used a method which was working fine but now it is giving an error. Instead of the thumbnail, it is now plain white in place of thumbnail.
`W/Glide: Load failed for /storage/emulated/0/Download/Ex26AAT.mp4 with size [-2147483648x-2147483648]`

`class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed to load resource There were 3 causes: java.io.IOException(java.lang.RuntimeException: setDataSource failed: status = 0x80000000) java.io.IOException(java.lang.RuntimeException: setDataSource failed: status = 0x80000000) java.io.IOException(java.lang.RuntimeException: setDataSource failed: status = 0x80000000)`.
I don't know why this is happening now. Here is the method

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyAdapter.MyViewHolder holder, int
        position) {

          Glide.with(activity)
            .load(items.get(position).getPath())
            .placeholder(android.R.drawable.alert_dark_frame)
            .error(android.R.drawable.stat_notify_error)
            .into(holder.thumbnail_img);
}
dependencies {

        implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.11.0'
        annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.11.0'
        implementation "com.github.bumptech.glide:okhttp3-integration:4.8.0"
}
```

Comment: Probably the problem is the path of your image. 
Try to load any image with a URL, if it works, then you image path is wrong.

Comment: I have checked the path as well and it is the correct one.

Comment: Did you try another library, like Picasso or Coil?